# A-Frame image/cursor does not point to the same object

Tags: aframe

I'm trying a similar example like Stereo-Sky A-Frame Component from [this](https://github.com/wallabyway/aframe-stereocube) link. The demo link does not work so I have uploaded the example [here](https://vr.langan.com/cube/) after fixing the source for `aframe-master.min.js`.

After viewing it in VR (in my samsung s7 edge with card board), I have found that the image for both eye does not align. Especially when I try putting the pointer on the way points, I have found they are off by small amount.

I'm confused what exactly I have done wrong; is the source for `A-Frame` is wrong? Or the images need to be "modified" for left and right eye? Is there a settings on the device that may be messing the image render? For ease of reference I am putting the source code : -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>A-Frame walkthrough (final)</title>
            <script src="https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/3620e8e/dist/aframe-master.min.js"></script>
            <script src="stereocube.js"></script>
        </head>
    <body>
      <a-scene>
        <a-assets>
          <img id="circle" src="circle.png"/>
        </a-assets>

        <a-camera stereocam position="-47 0 -35" ><a-cursor fuse="true" color="#2E3A87" timeout="700">
            <a-animation begin="cursor-click" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale" dur="800" 
                         fill="backwards" from="1.0 1.0 1.0" to="100 100 100">
            </a-animation>
        </a-camera>

        <a-mixin id="waypt" rotation="0 0 25" scale="2 2 2"></a-mixin>
        <a-mixin id="spin" attribute="rotation" dur="10000" fill="forwards" to="0 360 25" repeat="indefinite"></a-mixin>
        <a-mixin id="enter" begin="cursor-mouseenter" easing="ease-in" attribute="scale" dur="200" to="4 4 4"></a-mixin>
        <a-mixin id="leave" begin="cursor-mouseleave" easing="ease-out" attribute="scale" dur="200" to="2 2 2"></a-mixin>

        <a-box id="wp1" color="orange"    href="brooke0" position="-40 -10 10" mixin="waypt" src="#circle"> 
            <a-animation mixin="enter"></a-animation>
            <a-animation mixin="leave"></a-animation>
            <a-animation mixin="spin"></a-animation>
        </a-box>
        <a-box id="wp2" color="green"     href="brooke1" position="  0 -14  0" mixin="waypt" src="#circle" ><a-animation mixin="spin"></a-animation><a-animation  mixin="enter"></a-animation><a-animation  mixin="leave"></a-animation></a-box>
        <a-box id="wp3" color="lightblue" href="brooke3" position=" 15  -9 35" mixin="waypt" src="#circle"> <a-animation mixin="spin"></a-animation><a-animation  mixin="enter"></a-animation><a-animation  mixin="leave"></a-animation></a-box>
        <a-box id="wp4" color="red"       href="brooke2" position="-47 -9 -35" mixin="waypt" src="#circle"> <a-animation mixin="spin"></a-animation><a-animation  mixin="enter"></a-animation><a-animation  mixin="leave"></a-animation></a-box>

        <a-entity id="skyL" position="-47 0 -35" skycube="folder:brooke2L; eye:left" scale="1 1 -1"></a-entity>
        <a-entity id="skyR" position="-47 0 -35" skycube="folder:brooke2R; eye:right" scale="1 1 -1"></a-entity>
      </a-scene>
    </body>

    <script>

    var app = {
      init:  function() {
        // Add Click handler's to our waypoints in javascript
        [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('a-box'), function(box) {
            box.addEventListener('click', function () {
              window.setTimeout(function(){
                app.setSkybox ( box.getAttribute('href') );
                app.moveCamera ( box.getAttribute('position'), document.querySelectorAll('a-camera')[0] );
                app.hideWaypoints(box.id);
              },600)
            })
        });
        app.hideWaypoints("wp4");
      },

      setSkybox:  function(selectedFolder) {
        document.querySelector('#skyL').setAttribute('skycube',{folder: selectedFolder+"L", eye:"left"});
        document.querySelector('#skyR').setAttribute('skycube',{folder: selectedFolder+"R", eye:"right"});
      },

      hideWaypoints:  function(boxid) {
        document.querySelector('#wp4').setAttribute('visible',boxid === "wp1");
        document.querySelector('#wp2').setAttribute('visible',boxid != "wp4");
        document.querySelector('#wp3').setAttribute('visible',boxid != "wp4");
      },

      moveCamera:  function(newPosition, camera) {
        var pos = newPosition.x +" 0 "+ newPosition.z;
        camera.setAttribute('position', pos );
        // move the cubemap to the same position as the camera, to avoid distortion
        document.querySelector('#skyL').setAttribute('position', pos );
        document.querySelector('#skyR').setAttribute('position', pos );
      },
    }

    app.init();

    </script>

    </html>
```

Comment: I haven't looked at the component. Is it possibly a bug in the component? Does the main component example work if you try older A-Frame versions?

Comment: Its a good question, I have found `https://aframe.io/releases/0.5.0/aframe.min.js` is the latest. I have tried version `0.4.0` but problem stays same; version `0.3.0` may not have the cursor object but I could be wrong still the problem remains. I'm using stereocam which was mentioned in `wallabyway` [link](https://github.com/wallabyway/aframe-stereocube/blob/master/stereocube.js). I'm not sure how to proceed further. Any thoughts will be very helpful. Thanks :)

Comment: I also have this problem on an S7 and it seems it relates to this device.